Conditional MGF on Rademacher distribution
For a Rademacher r.v. X that is defined as
$$Pr[X = k]=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2}, \text{ for k=1} \\ \frac{1}{2}, \text{ for k=-1} \\ 0, \text{ otherwise}\end{cases} \tag{1}$$ or alternatively as
$$Pr[X = k] = \frac{ 1 }{ 2 } \left(  \delta \left( k - 1 \right) + \delta \left( k + 1 \right)  \right),\tag{2}$$
I am trying to compute the exact value or a lower bound of $E[e^{\lambda X}\mathbb{1}\{ t \leq X \leq t \gamma \}]$ with $\gamma \geq 1$ and $t \geq 0$.
Given the property of the indicator function
$$\mathbb{1}_{A\cap B} = \min\{\mathbb{1}_A,\mathbb{1}_B\} = \mathbb{1}_A \cdot\mathbb{1}_B \tag{3}$$ with $A = \{X \leq t \gamma\}$ and  $B = \{t \leq X\}$ I have written the following
$$E[e^{\lambda X}\mathbb{1}\{ t \leq X \leq t \gamma \}] = \min\left\{E[e^{\lambda X}\mathbb{1}\{ X \leq t \gamma \}], E[e^{\lambda X}\mathbb{1}\{t \leq X\}] \right\} = E[e^{\lambda X}\mathbb{1}\{ X \leq t \gamma \}\cdot \mathbb{1}\{ t \leq X\}]\tag{4}$$
Given the latter equation (please someone comment it's correctness), I decided to work on the terms inside $\min \{\cdot, \cdot \}$.
Given that $t \geq 0$, $\gamma \geq 1$, and $t \gamma \geq 0$, we evaluate the indicator function $\mathbb{1}\{ k \leq t \gamma \}$ for $k = 1$ and $k = -1$ as follows
$$\mathbb{1}\{ k \leq t \gamma \} =
\begin{cases}
\mathbb{1}\{ 1 \leq t \gamma \} =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } t \gamma \geq 1, \\
0, & \text{if } t \gamma \leq 1,
\end{cases} & \text{for } k = 1, \\
\mathbb{1}\{ -1 \leq t \gamma \} = 1 & \text{for } k = -1 \text{ (always true as $t \geq 0$ by definition)}.
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{align*}
E[e^{\lambda X}\mathbb{1}\{ A \}] &= E[e^{\lambda X}\mathbb{1}\{X \leq t \gamma  \}] \\
&= \sum_{k \in \{-1, 1\}} e^{\lambda k} P[X = k] \mathbb{1}\{k \leq t \gamma  \} \\
&= e^{-\lambda} P[X = -1]\mathbb{1}\{-1 \leq t \gamma  \} + e^{\lambda} P[X = 1]\mathbb{1}\{1 \leq t \gamma  \} \\
&= \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2} (e^{-\lambda} + e^{\lambda}), & \text{if } t \gamma \geq 1, \\
\frac{1}{2} e^{-\lambda}, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$
Similarly, given that $t \geq 0$, $\gamma \geq 1$, and $t \gamma \geq 0$, we evaluate the indicator function $\mathbb{1}\{ t \leq k \}$ for $k = 1$ and $k = -1$ as follows
$$\mathbb{1}\{ t \leq k \} =
\begin{cases}
\mathbb{1}\{ t \leq 1 \} =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } t \leq 1, \\
0, & \text{if } t > 1,
\end{cases} & \text{for } k = 1, \\
\mathbb{1}\{ t \leq -1 \} = 0 & \text{for } k = -1 \text{ (never true as $t \geq 0$ by definition)}.
\end{cases}$$
\begin{align*}
E[e^{\lambda X}\mathbb{1}\{ B \}] &= E[e^{\lambda X}\mathbb{1}\{t \leq X \}] \\
&= \sum_{k \in \{-1, 1\}} e^{\lambda k} P[X = k] \mathbb{1}\{t \leq k \} \\
&= e^{-\lambda} P[X = -1]\mathbb{1}\{t \leq -1 \} + e^{\lambda} P[X = 1]\mathbb{1}\{t \leq 1 \} \\
&= e^{\lambda} P[X = 1]\mathbb{1}\{t \leq 1 \} \\
&= \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2} e^{\lambda}, & \text{if } t \leq 1, \\
0, & \text{if } t > 1.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
I do not know how combine the results in $\min \{\cdot, \cdot \}$. It there another more elegant way to compute $E[e^{\lambda X}\mathbb{1}\{ t \leq X \leq t \gamma \}]$? Maybe a lower bound of $E[e^{\lambda X}\mathbb{1}\{ t \leq X \leq t \gamma \}]$ that will simplify the computations or working with the alternative definition of the Rademacher r.v. in $(2)$? Any help is highly appreciated.

I will try to work the case $$\mathbb{1}_{A\cap B} =  \mathbb{1}_A \cdot\mathbb{1}_B$$ and I will update the post. Maybe this way the cases will be simplified. Any comments on the rationale of the OP to catch serious mistakes are highly appreciated.

The middle step of Equation 4 should be the expectation of the minimum, rather than the minimum of expectations.  But its final result does hold.

@GrahamKemp thanks for the comment. I thought we could write
$$E[\min\left{e^{\lambda X}\mathbb{1}{ X \leq t \gamma }, e^{\lambda X}\mathbb{1}{t \leq X} \right}]=\min\left{E[e^{\lambda X}\mathbb{1}{ X \leq t \gamma }], E[e^{\lambda X}\mathbb{1}{t \leq X}] \right}$$
Isn't this correct?

We can compute directly from the definition,
$$
     \mathbb{E}(e^{\lambda X}1\{t \le X \le t\gamma\}) = e^{-\lambda}1\{t \le -1 \le t\gamma\}\mathbb{P}(X = -1) + e^{\lambda}1\{t \le 1 \le t\gamma\}\mathbb{P}(X = 1)
$$
Since $1\{t \le -1 \le t\gamma\} = 0$ for every $t \ge 0, \gamma \ge 1$, we left with
$$
    \mathbb{E}(e^{\lambda X}1\{t \le X \le t\gamma\}) = e^{\lambda}1\{t \le 1 \le t\gamma\}\mathbb{P}(X = 1) = \dfrac{e^\lambda}{2}1\left\{t \in \left[\dfrac{1}{\gamma}, 1\right]\right\}
$$

Thanks for your answer!

Sorry for my delayed comment. Can we say that this equation holds for any $\lambda$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

@Thoth Yes, it does
